# Open view with slide effect from top to bottom on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm making an application for iPhone, and I want that when I touch a button it opens a view with a slide effect when you touch from the top to the bottom of the screen. The view is in the same XIB file as the button...Advance thanks

Comment: **What have you tried?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need that use bellow code with your requirement simple with `GestureRecognizer`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];   
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:kAnimationKey];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addCustomBottomBar)] autorelease];
    swipeGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeGesture.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown);
    [yourDownViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureTop = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addCustomBottomBar)] autorelease];
    swipeGestureTop.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeGestureTop.direction = (UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp);
    [yourUpViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureTop];
 }
```

here you just set frame on of your this viewcontroller in `addCustomBottomBar` method like bellow...

```
-(void)addCustomBottomBar{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.window cache:YES];


    yourUpViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 70);//here you can also switch two ViewWith some flag otherwise create another method for anotherView....

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

2.if you want to Animation with up the ViewController with button Click then use bellow code.....

```
-(void)btnClicked{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.view cache:YES];

    if (yourflag) {

       yourViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 70);
    }
    else{
        yourflag=YES;
        yourViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 210, 320, 270);
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourViewController.view];
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

hope,this help you.....
:)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple animation -

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:myView];

[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480)];
[myView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```